# "Pushing" and resizing fragments

Tags: android, animation, fragment, transition

First I want to apologize if this is a duplicate I just could not find anything that would help me.
Anyway, I have an activity that hosts 2 fragments. Fragment A basically acts as a header(I couldn't use action bar for this situation), so Fragment A does not get touched. Under Fragment A is...Fragment B, which takes up the entire rest of the layout (under Fragment A)! Fragment B is simply a ListView fragment. What I want to do is when a user clicks something on the list (Fragment B), I want to "push" and resize Fragment B off to the left while another Fragment (Fragment C) gets pulled in from the right side of the screen. I just can't find any animations (which I need to brush up on) that can achieve this.

I thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat generic but I will try to point you in a general direction so that you may ask more specific questions.

Animations in Android only manipulate the frame-buffer. To succeed with what you are describing I would make it in stages. First do the animation then update the layout.

Good luck!